# Fields missing from Kafka message using Debezium PostgreSQL CDC Connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I have configured a PostgreSQL CDC Connector in Confluent, which is connected to an AWS RDS instance.

The messages from each table are being streamed into the topics but the structure for the JSON is

[image: Current JSON structure]

However, I was expecting something like this structure according to the docs (specifically with the **before**, **after**, and **op** fields)

[image: Expected structure]

I have tried setting the `REPLICA IDENTITY` to `FULL`, [according to the docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/connectors/postgresql.html#events), but it's still not working.

Any idea how I can get these fields?

Comment: can you provide the Debezium config you have used. Very likely you have used a transmit nett changes instead of the whole change record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out I was missing setting the after-state only parameter in Advanced Configuration to `false`.